# Convert a percentage to a "simple" ratio

Tags: code-golf, rational-numbers

[You run a political website](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2018-midterm-election-forecast/house/), and have determined that [people have a better intuitive understanding](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-media-has-a-probability-problem/) when the chance of winning or losing an election is expressed as a *ratio* ("5 in 7") than when it is expressed as a *percentage* ("71%").

But you also don't want to display confusing ratios like "58 in 82", you'd like them to be more easily understood, even if they aren't quite as precise.

So, **given a percentage between 0.1% and 99.9%, return the closest "easy-to-understand" ratio "*x in y*", using the following rules**:

1. Most values (see exceptions below) should return the **closest ratio out of 10 or lower**. 55% should return "5 in 9", not "11 in 20".
2. Ratios should be **reduced to their lowest terms**. 65% should return "2 in 3", not "4 in 6".
3. Values under 10% should return the **closest ratio of the form "*1 in n*" where *n* is one of (10,12,15,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)**. For example,  6% should return "1 in 15".
4. Values over 90% should return the **closest ratio of the form "*n-1 in n*" where *n* is one of (10,12,15,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)**. For example, 98.7% should return "79 in 80".
5. Values under 1% should return "**<1 in 100**"
6. Values over 99% should return "**>99 in 100**"

Or, to think about it another way, your program should return the **closest ratio from the following possible outputs** (I've included their approximate values for your convenience):

```
<1 in 100
 1 in 100  = 1.00%
 1 in 90   = 1.11%
 1 in 80   = 1.25%
 1 in 70   = 1.43%
 1 in 60   = 1.67%
 1 in 50   = 2.00%
 1 in 40   = 2.50%
 1 in 30   = 3.33%
 1 in 20   = 5.00%
 1 in 15   = 6.67%
 1 in 12   = 8.33%
 1 in 10   = 10.00%
 1 in 9    = 11.11%
 1 in 8    = 12.50%
 1 in 7    = 14.29%
 1 in 6    = 16.67%
 1 in 5    = 20.00%
 2 in 9    = 22.22%
 1 in 4    = 25.00%
 2 in 7    = 28.57%
 3 in 10   = 30.00%
 1 in 3    = 33.33%
 3 in 8    = 37.50%
 2 in 5    = 40.00%
 3 in 7    = 42.86%
 4 in 9    = 44.44%
 1 in 2    = 50.00%
 5 in 9    = 55.56%
 4 in 7    = 57.14%
 3 in 5    = 60.00%
 5 in 8    = 62.50%
 2 in 3    = 66.67%
 7 in 10   = 70.00%
 5 in 7    = 71.43%
 3 in 4    = 75.00%
 7 in 9    = 77.78%
 4 in 5    = 80.00%
 5 in 6    = 83.33%
 6 in 7    = 85.71%
 7 in 8    = 87.50%
 8 in 9    = 88.89%
 9 in 10   = 90.00%
 11 in 12  = 91.67%
 14 in 15  = 93.33%
 19 in 20  = 95.00%
 29 in 30  = 96.67%
 39 in 40  = 97.50%
 49 in 50  = 98.00%
 59 in 60  = 98.33%
 69 in 70  = 98.57%
 79 in 80  = 98.75%
 89 in 90  = 98.89%
 99 in 100 = 99.00%
>99 in 100
```

**Other stipulations:**

- Numeric input can be in the range of **0.1 to 99.9** or in the range of **0.001 to 0.999**, whichever is more convenient. You must handle at least 3 significant digits.
- You must output a *ratio* ("3 in 4"), not the equivalent *fraction* ("3/4").
- If there are two ratios equally close to the input, your program can return either one. 7.5% could return "1 in 12" or "1 in 15".
- Leading/trailing white space and/or new lines are fine

**Examples**:

```
Input  :   Output
 0.5   :  <1 in 100
 1.0   :   1 in 100
 1.5   :   1 in 70
 7.5   :   1 in 15  or  1 in 12 (either is acceptable)
 9.2   :   1 in 10
13.1   :   1 in 8
29.2   :   2 in 7
29.3   :   3 in 10
52.7   :   1 in 2
52.8   :   5 in 9
72.0   :   5 in 7
73.9   :   3 in 4
88.8   :   8 in 9
90.8   :   9 in 10
94.2   :  19 in 20
98.7   :  79 in 80
98.9   :  89 in 90
99.0   :  99 in 100
99.1   : >99 in 100
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, shortest code in each language wins.

(Similar to, but not duplicate of: [Convert a decimal to a fraction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17239/convert-a-decimal-to-a-fraction), [Closest fraction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26278/closest-fraction), [Approximate floating point number with n-digit precision](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/143016/approximate-floating-point-number-with-n-digit-precision))

Comment: `If there are two ratios equally close to the input, your program can return either one. 7.5% could return "1 in 12" or "1 in 15"` Does that mean that we can return `7 in 100` as well? Btw, `1 in 14` is closer to the input in this case.

Comment: @DimChtz No, as that violates rule 3 (values under 10% should be expressed as "1 in *n*", for specific possible values of *n*).

Comment: Ohh, I didn't notice this. Okay.

Comment: I'd like it if we could just output the numerator and denominator as any format like a tuple/list or something, but there are already competing answers so I suppose it's too late for this challenge. For future challenges though, I'd consider a more flexible I/O format because some languages lose more competitiveness than others when you require string handling.

Comment: @BradC - LOL. I was just at 538, and I was all "Wow! I gotta make a golfing challenge out of this!"

Answer (score 6):

## T-SQL, 385 bytes

```sql
SELECT TOP 1IIF(i>.99,'>',IIF(i<.01,'<',''))+n+' in '+d
FROM t,(SELECT ISNULL(PARSENAME(value,2),'1')n,PARSENAME(value,1)d FROM
STRING_SPLIT('100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,15,12,10,9,8,7,6,5,2.9,4,2.7,3.10,3,3.8,2.5,3.7,4.9,2,5.9,4.7,3.5,5.8,2.3,7.10,5.7,3.4,7.9,4.5,5.6,6.7,7.8,8.9,9.10,11.12,14.15,19.20,29.30,39.40,49.50,59.60,69.70,79.80,89.90,99.100',','))m
ORDER BY ABS(i-ABS(n)/d)
```

Input is via pre-existing table **t** with numeric field **i**, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

That input table is joined with an in-memory table parsed from a string via `STRING_SPLIT` (which separates rows) and `PARSENAME` (which separates numerator and denominator via `.`).

The table is sorted by distance from the input value **i**, and returns the top row, formatted appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>164</s> <s>159</s> 144 bytes

Expects an input ratio in \$]0,1[\$.

```javascript
r=>(g=m=>--n+11?g((q=n>1?n*10:n+10-~'13'[n],d=((p=r<.1?1:r>.9?q-1:n<0&&r*q+.5|0)/q-r)**2)>m?m:(o=p+' in '+q,d)):r<.01?'<'+o:r>.99?'>'+o:o)(n=11)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddLbboMgGADg@z0FVxW0Ij/WCEbgQZZdND2lSwuVLrta9urOmmypwO6AfPwneN9@bu87f759lNbtD@NRjV5pfFJXpcvSFgDmhPGgrAZjc2DddMTK7wzq7NW@rfcK45vyPQUDnddUmqGEzvZstfL5UNDmi5FqKD3Jc0701Vw77NStyNDZoqwY1ntCuuk2A5P1WeHmENJk@rF2BFsFQMads3d3OdCLO@EjRow2qELAGCGoqlAPj2DT9iVwQNmzQ/@7JnZtxNoUgwYh5383PLwjKU@VEDCoKcRMBIqHwfhcZ6zqhaqTKRtO2zglj5VYqOahZKBaHgy6SRXW1lTGhW0CJUSQUaQyShYomWxSbpYTg5nxiInlLNqZiQRbNCBmJiMml9OQMv3tJvf86PrPjT8)

#### How?

We try all possible ratios \$p/q\$. For each of them, we compute:

$$d=(p/q-r)^2$$

We update the best score \$m\$ (the lower, the better) each time \$d\$ is lower than or equal to \$m\$.

We go from the highest value of \$q\$ to the lowest one, so that a smaller denominator is preferred in case of a tie.

#### Commented

```javascript
r => (g = m =>               // r = input; g() = recursive function, taking m = best score
  --n + 11 ?                 // decrement n; if n is still greater than or equal to -10:
    g(                       //   do a recursive call to g():
      ( q =                  //     compute q = denominator:
        n > 1 ?              //       if n is greater than 1:
          n * 10             //         q = n * 10 (20, 30, ..., 100)
        :                    //       else:
          n + 10 - ~'13'[n], //         q = 12 if n = 0, 15 if n = 1, n + 11 if n < 0
        d = ((               //     compute d = (p / q - r)²:
          p =                //       compute p = numerator:
          r < .1 ?           //         if r is less than 0.01:
            1                //           p = 1
          :                  //         else:
            r > .9 ?         //           if r is greater than 0.90:
              q - 1          //             p = q - 1
            :                //           else:
              n < 0 &&       //             if n is negative (i.e. q is in [1,10]):
              r * q + .5 | 0 //               p = round(r * q)
                             //             otherwise: p = 0 (which will be ignored)
          ) / q - r          //       compute p / q - r
        ) ** 2               //       and square the result (cheaper than absolute value)
      ) > m ?                //     if d is greater than m:
        m                    //       leave m unchanged
      : (                    //     else:
        o = p + ' in ' + q,  //       update the output string o
        d                    //       and update m to d
    ))                       //   end of recursive call
  :                          // else (all possible ratios have been tried out):
    r < .01 ? '<' + o :      //   if r is less than 0.01, prefix with '<'
    r > .99 ? '>' + o :      //   if r is greater than 0.99, prefix with '>'
    o                        //   otherwise, just return o
)(n = 11)                    // initial call to g() with m = n = 11
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 84 bytes

```
ＮθＦ¹¹«Ｆ⊖ι⊞υ⟦⊕κι⟧≔⎇⊖ι∨×χι¹²¦¹⁵ιＦ²⊞υ⟦∨κ⊖ιι⟧»≔Ｅυ↔⁻θ∕§ι⁰§ι¹η≔⌕η⌊ηη×<‹θ·⁰¹×>›θ·⁹⁹⪫§υη in
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBRS8MwFIWf119x6dMNxNFOFIoyKIhScbqHvYkPXZvZy9bbLWmGIv72mpSqpXkISe75zjmkqHJdNPmh6zI@2vbZ1lul8SRugl2jAeNYwFcw6893qtCqVtyqEkkIWFtToZXwmvH/YC8k0JvDZ6kx9M64UZpz/TmhJbxo3FCtDMaRI9xDvPDblec93kcuRikO2EuYlBjCvoMhbZUfvTjdGlwRW4Mnh9CZSoVpm3GpPpAkRI4bXWPhl4TKOQ0@98QlVhKcCdW2xup3vtbE7dA8vA0lPCnTp8wjbzMRLJ3gQau89X/qNEky0jw2xH@trLeXEAIxhE7TddH88jrpLs6HHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a decimal rather than a percentage. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the fraction.

```
Ｆ¹¹«
```

Run from \$ n = 0 \$ to \$ n = 10 \$.

```
Ｆ⊖ι⊞υ⟦⊕κι⟧
```

Generate ratios for \$ \frac 1 n \$ to \$ \frac {n - 1} n \$.

```
≔⎇⊖ι∨×χι¹²¦¹⁵ι
```

Get the \$ n^{th} \$ element of the list \$ 12, 15, 20 ... 100 \$ into \$ n \$.

```
Ｆ²⊞υ⟦∨κ⊖ιι⟧»
```

Generate ratios for \$ \frac {n - 1} n \$ and \$ \frac 1 n \$.

```
≔Ｅυ↔⁻θ∕§ι⁰§ι¹η
```

Calculate the decimal values of all the ratios and take the absolute difference with the original input.

```
≔⌕η⌊ηη
```

Find the index of the least absolute difference. In case of a tie (e.g. \$ \frac 1 2 \$ and \$ \frac 2 4 \$), take the ratio generated first.

```
×<‹θ·⁰¹
```

Print a `<` if the input is less than \$ 0.01 \$.

```
×>›θ·⁹⁹
```

Print a `>` if the input is greater than \$ 0.99 \$.

```
⪫§υη in
```

Join the numerator and denominator of the appropriate ratio with `in` and print.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>261</s> <s>278</s> <s>261</s> <s>237</s> 177 bytes

```python
lambda n:' <>'[(n<.01)-(n>.99)]+'%d in %d'%min([(a,b)for b in[[12,15]+r(10,110,10),r(1,11)][.1<n<.9]for a in r([1,b-1][n>.9],[b,2][n<.1])],key=lambda(a,b):abs(1.*a/b-n))
r=range
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdHRboIwFAbge5/iJIuhnZX1FBmtQV@k60WrOMm0GuTGp3eAaNq5C5KWD/7zF87Xdn/y4rZbfd0O9ui2FvwygXKdaOLLlCOdE79OlaJmlky3UHuYbpPpsfZEE8sc3Z0acN1trVEwzM2sIcgZ9henrNt0a2p0imUXp0z/uO1TGqKRuTka3ccbph0T3bpM0VDDfqrr6l5nGLK07kIwfbcfbu4pnTSrxvrv6nZuat/CjvCU85wCvAGU2Kcj55MAuyoDwr@Yh/gZWREZ5gBd/3EjgFR1u68aqC9gN5vq3Fp3qGj4vhLx4MAww9BkQOL5muipiCgbKXtJzEURJoqI5Eh5TyqgQvCQwmFFpsJhi4CkfATKv4GKP0i9VFSL8WQ4mIhMjvWLwWRsYxM5mIpMjQdQ6vXvKnX/yusn3n4B)

Comment: Doesn't Python support semicolons? You could replace `'\n '` with `';'`... unless I'm wrong.

Comment: @BradC Fixed :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 58 bytes

```
⁵R×⁵;12,15µ’,1,€)Ẏ;⁵Œc¤ð÷/ạ¥ÞḢj“ in ”
”<”>“”>.99$?<.01$?;Ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R49agw9OBpLWhkY6h6aGtjxpm6hjqPGpao/lwV581UOLopORDSw5vOLxd/@GuhYeWHp73cMeirEcNcxQy8xQeNczlAmIbILYDCoEoPUtLFXsbPQNDFXvrw@3///83AIpYAgA)

-16 bytes thanks to Arnauld (can just prepend the `<` and `>` instead of rewriting the whole phrase)
-6 bytes and bug-fixes thanks to Jonathan Allan

Comment: @Arnauld Oh you're right, never thought about that :P Thanks!

Comment: `0.3` should result in `3 in 10` not `2 in 7`

Comment: You should just remove the `µµ`, no? EDIT - and then golf `ÐṂṂ` to `ÞḢ`

Comment: changing `9` to `⁵` should resolve the bug I believe.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh whoops, yep I wasn't using 10 as a valid denominator. Thanks. And no, removing the double mu doesn't work because then the "minimum" is attached to the right side of the dyadic link-min function which is definitely not what I want, but only putting one mu doesn't seem to fix it. Thanks for the golf though :D

Comment: Removing the double mu from the previous seems to [work fine](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R49agw9OBpLWhkY6h6aGtjxpm6hjqPGpaA2Q2rXm4q8/aMujQkoKEQ0sObzi8Xf/hroWHlh6e8HBnExBlPWqYo5CZp/CoYS4XENsAsR1QCETpWVqq2NvoGRiq2Fsfbv9/uB1oWOT//3oGBoY6CgZ6EMIURJqD2ZYWYNISQloCAA) ...although I noticed another bug - namely `0.999` results in `>1 in 1` - which can be fixed by replacing `⁵R¤p`¤` with `⁵Œc¤` this also saves another two bytes :)

Comment: `µ€` -> `)` saves another

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh cool, thanks! Is the mu-euro => ) a new thing?

Comment: Fairly new, been there since May. You left in a redundant `¤` by the way.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah ok, that's about when I last used Jelly :( :P and oh yeah, thanks, I was wondering where the third byte you saved went lol.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>53</s>  52 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
_.01,.99Ṡµ<0ịØ<ḣE⁵Ż×⁵+12,5Ṡ,’Ɗż€$Ẏ;⁵Œc¤÷/ạ¥Þ³Ḣj“ in
```

A full program which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWkAlv9qZWxsef//Xy4wMSwuOTnhuaDCtTww4buLw5g84bijReKBtcW7w5figbUrMTIsNeG5oCzigJnGisW84oKsJOG6jjvigbXFkmPCpMO3L@G6ocKlw57Cs@G4omrigJwgaW4g////MC4wMDE)**

Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##Jcu7CsIwFAbgV@ngIpaapJb0YFefQsRBHCzi7lZFEBQcXFS84HUQxE206pRQ3yN5kZg003fO@f8Tt7vdvlJND2HXAxDpnj0iJD5TvozE61STg0f24QtNCRM30Lkrk9Vvkn3l8FYQ71nVNOYtdubPsngf2IXv2F28jrFMNk6n58hkq1jKriId8bEuP/VQFOlax0rVkYdQ4DoajCx2oxYgBuxjA7EbAd8QEGoJDZTk79QHQxjmR0CWSv4HIbXkFQBkwY0/)

Note that the test-suite is altered to make the code a monadic link by:

1. using the register keep a track of the current "program input", with
   `³` to `®`; and
2. closing the list of characters code for " in ", with
   `“ in`  to `“ in ”`

#### How?

Starts with code that forces any necessary printing of the `<` or `>` sign and then code which constructs all the numerator-denominator pairs (with some redundant not simplified form versions, all after their simplified form) and prints the minimally different division-evaluated entry using a stable sort joined with  `in` .

```
_.01,.99Ṡµ<0ịØ<ḣE⁵Ż×⁵+12,5Ṡ,’Ɗż€$Ẏ;⁵Œc¤÷/ạ¥Þ³Ḣj“ in  - Main Link: number in [0,1], n
 .01,.99                                             - literal pair = [0.01, 0.99]
_                                                    - subtract -> [n - 0.01, n - 0.99]
        Ṡ                                            - sign (vectorises) (-1 if <0; 1 if >0; else 0) 
         µ                                           - start a new monadic link
                                                     -   call that X
          <0                                         - less than zero? (vectorises)
             Ø<                                      - literal list of characters = "<>"
            ị                                        - index into (vectorises) ("<<" if n < 0.01; ">>" if n >= 0.99; else "><")
                E                                    - all (of X) equal? (1 if ((n < 0.01) OR (n > 0.99)) else 0
               ḣ                                     - head to index ("<" if n < 0.01; ">" if n > 0.99; else "")
                                                     -   (the following nilad forces a print of that)
                 ⁵                                   - literal 10
                  Ż                                  - zero-range -> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
                   ×⁵                                - multiply by 10 -> [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
                      12,5                           - literal pair = [12,5]
                     +                               - add -> [12,15,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
                                $                    - last two links as a monad
                             Ɗ                       -   last three links as a monad
                          Ṡ                          -     sign -> [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
                            ’                        -     decrement -> [11,14,19,29,39,49,59,69,79,89,99]
                           ,                         -     pair -> [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[11,14,19,29,39,49,59,69,79,89,99]]
                              ż€                     -   zip with for €ach -> [[[1,12],[1,15],[1,20],[1,30],[1,40],[1,50],[1,60],[1,70],[1,80],[1,90],[1,100]],[[11,12],[14,15],[19,20],[29,30],[39,40],[49,50],[59,60],[69,70],[79,80],[89,90],[99,100]]]
                                 Ẏ                   - tighten -> [[1,12],[1,15],[1,20],[1,30],[1,40],[1,50],[1,60],[1,70],[1,80],[1,90],[1,100],[11,12],[14,15],[19,20],[29,30],[39,40],[49,50],[59,60],[69,70],[79,80],[89,90],[99,100]]
                                      ¤              - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                                   ⁵                 -   literal 10
                                    Œc               -   unordered pairs -> [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[1,7],[1,8],[1,9],[1,10],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],[2,7],[2,8],[2,9],[2,10],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7],[3,8],[3,9],[3,10],[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[4,8],[4,9],[4,10],[5,6],[5,7],[5,8],[5,9],[5,10],[6,7],[6,8],[6,9],[6,10],[7,8],[7,9],[7,10],[8,9],[8,10],[9,10]]
                                  ;                  - concatenate -> [[1,12],[1,15],[1,20],[1,30],[1,40],[1,50],[1,60],[1,70],[1,80],[1,90],[1,100],[11,12],[14,15],[19,20],[29,30],[39,40],[49,50],[59,60],[69,70],[79,80],[89,90],[99,100],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[1,7],[1,8],[1,9],[1,10],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],[2,7],[2,8],[2,9],[2,10],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7],[3,8],[3,9],[3,10],[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[4,8],[4,9],[4,10],[5,6],[5,7],[5,8],[5,9],[5,10],[6,7],[6,8],[6,9],[6,10],[7,8],[7,9],[7,10],[8,9],[8,10],[9,10]]
                                           Þ         - sort by:
                                          ¥          -   last two links as a dyad:
                                                     -       ...(with right argument of
                                            ³        -           the program input, n)
                                        /            -     reduce by:
                                       ÷             -       division
                                         ạ           -     absolute difference
                                             Ḣ       - head
                                               “ in  - literal list of characters " in "
                                              ;      - concatenate
                                                     - implicit print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>224</s> <s>198</s> 197 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Data.List,Text
t=toReal
$p=if(p<1.0)"<"if(p>99.0)">"""+snd(minimum[(abs(p-t n*1E2/t d),n<+" in "<+d)\\i<-[10,12,15:[20,30..100]],(n,d)<-[(1,i),(i-1,i):diag2[1..10][1..10]]|gcd n d<2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZJNb5wwEIbP5VeMnBxM1lBsgsARu6fkUCmRqqY3loODvStLYNDirVKpv72Ur2VZ9eTx83rembFdlEqYrqrluVRQCW06XTX1ycK7lS/mF3kWVvivurXkp/q0jt3a@ocSpXPfbPUBNyn1AxelaIh3nA@bHUJo0xqJK210da4yLD5a3HgWzAN9YV8tSJeYdINAG0DpRrr7vU69jAaEMkKjp4wFJAx8nwZBnhNsiHR7GVOiXYK1N6xPUosjy@hwKJ@X/M@xkGBApix3u3crTta5A6ta28IWMhz4EYEMpXSo23uj3CXOF9wPMOD/aLTQ@ALjFaQRIjCHbNa5z1ZWF6fQpwtNZsjmo2z0v8JwgOFNfsT8eMlnV5gMMBogv7THplGitWkc@nwxfZxhkkzpyTqdBxPkN@X54zzUiNmCk6mreMTJCo/VkhHzBfOpM85vb7nn493s1kLev9rhbAqra9M/3L2zBWEkZLp9U9WHOgFe1EadCmWsOCoX1GejCqsk7PeArwJZBBdSb/oOefe3OJTi2Hbet9fu@bcRlS6mzfdS2EN9qv4B)

Explained:

```
t = toReal                              // give `toReal` a shorter name
$ p
 = if(p < 1.0)                          // if the percentage is less than 1%
  "<"                                   // prepend "<"
 if(p > 99.0)                           // if the percentage is > 99%
  ">"                                   // prepend ">"
  ""                                    // otherwise prepend nothing
 + snd (                                // to the second element of
  minimum [                             // the smallest item in a list composed of
   (                                    // pairs of
    abs (                               // the absolute value of
     p -                                // the difference between the percentage
     t n*1E2 / t d                      // and the ratio
    ) 
   ,                                    // associated with
    n <+ " in " <+ d                    // the string representation of the ratio
   )                                    // in the form of a tuple
   \\ i <- [10, 12, 15: [20, 30..100]]  // for every special denominator `i`
   , (n, d) <- [(1, i), (i - 1, i): diag2 [1..10] [1..10]]
                                        // for every ratio `n` : `d`
   | gcd n d < 2                        // where `n` / `d` cannot be further simplified
  ]
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 118 bytes

```perl6
{'<'x(.01>$_)~'>'x($_>.99)~(|(1..9 X ^11),|map({|(1,$_-1 X$_)},12,15,|(^11 X*10))).min({abs $_-[/] @^a}).join(' in ')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY7RaoNAEEV/5T5Id6dsJjtrjQ6k0s8QSiMGKqTUJCQvDWp@3Y4Pc5h7OTBz/b797pbhgZce78vo9u7Pc5Q6a@npagtZW7MqPf3khVnR4CBCYRq6qx@tC1m7ETTmz0FSkCJM3gw0rxKJiIfT2Y/d8Q7zPrdf@Dh0M/HPxWqH0xmO5uXePdDbpa3ESOgvN@wjFxCONgVKG@UEyVmQ1s2Qo0hcrqhQJjPL3L6rKosaV7yZp5UpBoWqKQapl38)